# How to map function pointer argument of a function in a subsubsection of Doxygen?

Tags: c, function-pointers, doxygen

I have a C function that takes pointer to a function as on of the argument.

```
 /**
 * @brief Description of your function.
 * @param a arg1 pointer.
 * @param func Description of the function pointer argument.
 * @param c arg2 pointer.
 */

 int MyFunc(int *a, Std_ReturnType (*func)(int* b), int* c);
```

I want to write documentation using doxygen. In doxygen, I want to map this function using `\subsubsection`  from a new page like below

```
\section mysection Page1 

\subsubsection MyFuncsubsec MyFunc(int* a, Std_ReturnType (*func)(int* b), int* c)
int MyFunc(int *a, Std_ReturnType (*func)(int* b), int* c)
```

I want to point this function name in the doxygen.

**Example:**

If `Myfunction_Test` is a function, then I want to point like this using below code.

```
\subsection Myfunctiontest Myfunction_Test(const uint16 a)
Myfunction_Test(const uint16 a)
```

When I click that function link, it will jump to function definition in the doxygen. It is working as expected.

[image]

But in my case, One the argument is a function pointer. After generating doxygen, I can see like below. There is no corresponding link is generating due to function pointer.

[image]

How can I map correctly this function using `\subsubsection` in doxygen?

Comment: As far as I am aware, Doxygen does not support that.  Sub- and subsubsections are a higher level of organization than individual function documentation.

Comment: Regardless of Doxygen, you should be doing `typedef Std_ReturnType myfunc (int* b);` then declare the parameter as `myfunc* func`. Now the reader of your code is happy and Doxygen is happen. You may lose the International Obfuscated C Code Contest, but we can't win them all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Never post on SO from a phone... Anyway, this might be the correct answer to the question I suppose, but it was a long time since I last used Doxygen and I'm unable to verify it.

Comment: @Lundin do you mean like this    `typedef Std_ReturnType myfunc (int* b);
int MyFunc(int *a, myfunc* func, int* c);`

Comment: @user2986042 Yes. Doxygen ought to understand that better too, I think.